# setColHeading in Matlab is giving error message

Tags: matlab

I have a table in Matlab and I want to change the column header.
So I use setColHeading. But Matlab keeps giving me the error:

Undefined function 'setColHeading' for input arguments of type 'table'.

Why? If not setColHeading, how to change the heading of a table?

The reason I want to change the heading is that I have a table of
just one column that is a set of dates in it. I want to make it to be two columns, with the additional column to be the previous date (the first column minus 1, but they have to be all business dates).

Here is an example table:

```
   CurrentDate       
_______________________

'2015-06-23 00:00:00.0'
'2015-06-22 00:00:00.0'
'2015-06-19 00:00:00.0'
'2015-06-18 00:00:00.0'
'2015-06-17 00:00:00.0'
'2015-06-16 00:00:00.0'
'2015-06-15 00:00:00.0'
'2015-06-12 00:00:00.0'
```

I want to add a column prevDate:

```
  CurrentDate       
_______________________

'2015-06-22 00:00:00.0'
'2015-06-19 00:00:00.0'
'2015-06-18 00:00:00.0'
'2015-06-17 00:00:00.0'
'2015-06-16 00:00:00.0'
'2015-06-15 00:00:00.0'
'2015-06-12 00:00:00.0'
```

......

Thanks!

Jen

Comment: I'm afraid [setColHeading](http://www.mathworks.com/help/slvnv/ref/modeladvisor.table.setcolheading.html) seems to be part of Simulink and not Matlab.

Comment: So do you need to add a column with a specific header or only change the header?

Comment: I need to add a new column with specific column. Thank you!

Comment: You are right, it might be part of simulink. What can I do if without simulink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the name of (for example) the second column of a table `t`, you can write:

```
t.Properties.VariableNames{2} = 'newName'
```

If you have a table containing a single column of dates/numbers - let's say that column is called `myDate` - and you want to create a new column that is the first column minus 1, you can write

```
t.PrevDate = t.myDate - 1
```

If you need them to be business dates, you'll need to do something more complex than just subtracting 1, but this gives you the general syntax.

Comment: Still trying....that line: t.PrevDate = t.myDate - 1 gives me: error: Undefined function minus...

Comment: I just keep getting this error: Undefined function 'minus' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Comment: OK, you've edited the question to make it clear that your dates are stored as strings rather than numbers. In that case, instead of just subtracting one you'll need to convert from from a string to a number (see `datenum`), subtract one, then convert back to a string.